# How to fix signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm getting an error message in Codeblocks C++ 'Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault' in comparison between a vector element and a size of vector of vectors inside for loop (line 133 `if (parz_przestrzenie[i] != parz_dystanse[i].size())`).

Could anyone tell me why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int bloki_parz[100000], bloki_nieparz[100000];

int silnia(int n)
{
    int liczba = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        liczba *= i;
    }
    return liczba;
}

int main()
{
    int n, czapka, wolne_miejsca = 0, wynik = 1;
    vector<int> parz, nieparz, parz_przestrzenie, nieparz_przestrzenie, parz_przestrzenie2, nieparz_przestrzenie2;
    vector<vector<int>> parz_dystanse;
    vector<vector<int>> nieparz_dystanse;

    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cin >> czapka;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            parz.push_back(czapka);
        }
        else
        {
            nieparz.push_back(czapka);
        }
    }
    int parz_size = parz.size(), nieparz_size = nieparz.size();
    // sprawdzamy czy dane nie sÂą sprzeczne ; gdy zabraknie nam miejsc do rozmieszczania
    vector<int> parz_duplicate = parz;
    vector<int> nieparz_duplicate = nieparz;
    parz_duplicate.erase(unique(parz_duplicate.begin(), parz_duplicate.end()), parz_duplicate.end());
    nieparz_duplicate.erase(unique(nieparz_duplicate.begin(), nieparz_duplicate.end()), nieparz_duplicate.end());
    int parz_dupl_size = parz_duplicate.size(), nieparz_dupl_size = nieparz_duplicate.size();

    if (parz_size < nieparz_dupl_size)
    {
        cout << 0 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (nieparz_size < parz_dupl_size)
    {
        cout << 0 << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < parz_size - 1; i++)
    {
        if (parz[i] == parz[i + 1])
        {
            bloki_parz[i + 1] = 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nieparz_size - 1; i++)
    {
        if (nieparz[i] == nieparz[i + 1])
        {
            bloki_nieparz[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < parz_size; i++)
    {
        vector<int> bloczek;
        for (int j = i; j < parz_size; j++)
        {
            if (parz[j] != parz[j + 1])
            {
                bloczek.push_back(parz[j]);
            }
            else
            {
                i += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (bloczek.size() != 0)
        {
            parz_dystanse.push_back(bloczek);
        }
    }
    int parz_dyst_size = parz_dystanse.size();
    if (parz[parz_size - 1] != parz[parz_size - 2])
    {
        parz_dystanse[parz_dyst_size - 1].push_back(parz[parz_size - 1]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nieparz_size; i++)
    {
        vector<int> bloczek;
        for (int j = i; j < nieparz_size; j++)
        {
            if (nieparz[j] != nieparz[j + 1])
            {
                bloczek.push_back(nieparz[j]);
            }
            else
            {
                i += 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (bloczek.size() != 0)
        {
            nieparz_dystanse.push_back(bloczek);
        }
    }

    int nieparz_dyst_size = nieparz_dystanse.size();

    int current_wynik = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nieparz_size; i++)
    {
        if (bloki_parz[i] == 0)
        {
            current_wynik++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (current_wynik != 0)
            {
                parz_przestrzenie.push_back(current_wynik);
            }
            current_wynik = 0;
        }
    }
    parz_przestrzenie.push_back(current_wynik);

    current_wynik = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < parz_size; i++)
    {
        if (bloki_nieparz[i] == 0)
        {
            current_wynik++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (current_wynik != 0)
            {
                nieparz_przestrzenie.push_back(current_wynik);
            }
            current_wynik = 0;
        }
    }
    nieparz_przestrzenie.push_back(current_wynik);

    int parz_przest_size = parz_przestrzenie.size(), nieparz_przest_size = nieparz_przestrzenie.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        if (parz_przestrzenie[i] != parz_dystanse[i].size())
        {
            wynik *= parz_przestrzenie[i];
            wolne_miejsca++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nieparz_przest_size; i++)
    {
        if (nieparz_przestrzenie[i] != nieparz_dystanse[i].size())
        {
            wynik *= nieparz_przestrzenie[i];
            wolne_miejsca++;
        }
    }

    cout << wynik * silnia(wolne_miejsca) << endl;
}
```

Comment: If that's where you fault is, then either of those vectors are likely being breached when you index with `i`. Debug your code further to discover why.

Comment: You didn't show what input causes the crash. Try building with the address sanitizer (`-fsanitize=address`) - it will likely point you straight at the bug.

Answer (score 0):

`parz_dystanse` is a vector of a vector. In this case the return value of `parz_dystanse.size()` is a long unsigned int, whereas an element of `parz_przestrzenie` is an int.

You need to make explicit that `parz_dystanse.size()` returns an int in order to make comparitions between integer expressions of different signedness.

This will fix that problem:

```
if (parz_przestrzenie[i] != (int)parz_dystanse[i].size())
```